# WooCommerce: How to save an information to variation data without explicit field in backend

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to save an information to the variation data without defining an explicit field in my backend.

I already create the information in my functions.php for each variation. But I do not want an explicit field (e.g. described [here](https://www.proy.info/how-to-add-woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/)) because it is a dynamic value (delivery time) which is calculated on runtime when user enters the product page.  I just want to save the information in the variation data, so I can access and display it via variation.php by this code:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-cmpzDeliveryTime">
{{{ data.variation.variation_cmpzDeliveryTime}}}
</div>
```

But unfortunately, I am not finding a solution. :(
Is this possible after all? Could anybody help me please?

**/UPDATE: I found a solution, here is my code:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'cmpz_load_variation_products_fields' );
function cmpz_load_variation_products_fields( $variations ) {
  $variations['variation_cmpzDeliveryTime'] = cmpzGetBBDateForVariation( $variations[ 'variation_id' ] ) ;
  return $variations;
}

function cmpzGetBBDateForVariation ( $variation_id ) {
       //DO SOME CODING
       return $cmpzDeliveryTime;
}
```

And this comes in variation.php:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-cmpzDeliveryTime">{{{ data.variation.variation_cmpzDeliveryTime}}}</div>
```